# how to return a single element in a php array using angluarjs

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays

Here is my code

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$customer_array = array();

$customer1 = array(
  'customer_id' => '1',
  'name' => 'Larry',
  'city' => 'Houston'
);
$customer_array[] = $customer1;

$customer2 = array(
  'customer_id' => '2',
  'name' => 'tom',
  'city' => 'Hoff'
);
$customer_array[] = $customer2;

echo json_encode($customer_array);
}
```

and this is the Angular part

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.post("customers.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data
  });
});
```

How would I modify my controller to pull both customer1 and customer2 arrays or either customer1 and customer2?  So, in short both arrays or only one.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but it seems like you want to add a parameter to your POST method to decide which array to return?

Comment: How do you do that?  And what do I do with the angular code, I'm very new to angularJS, I appreciate the tip.

Comment: You aren't sending any data with `$http.post()`. Send something that indicates which data you want returned